# What Planet or System are Orion Slave Girls Actually From?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, star-trek-enterprise

[image]

Orion slave girls have been with *Star Trek* since, literally, the beginning of Trek.  (This image is Vina, as slave girl, in *The Cage*.)

Okay, I know -- they're from Orion.  But Orion is a constellation.  And, while it's likely that in the original pilot, the name was used because it was recognizable, was the location discussed later in the series?

Was it a name used by non-native species because they were from a star within the constellation?  Or are they not even from anywhere related to the constellation?

Comment: And more importantly, how do I get there?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Orion_system

> The Orion system was a star system and home of the Orion civilization. (VOY: "Good Shepherd")
>
> According to Star Trek: Star Charts, on page 36, this system was, also, named Pi 3 Orionis. This system was located 26 light years from Earth. Furthermore, according to the same source, this system was located in the Beta Quadrant.

As per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi%C2%B3_Orionis):

> Pi3 Orionis (π3 Ori, π3 Orionis), formally designated Tabit, is a white F-type dwarf star approximately 26 light-years away in the constellation of Orion

So, they ARE indeed from Orion constellation according to Star Trek: Star Charts

Comment: Though note that the stars in the Orion constellation are nowhere near each other. Some of them are further from each other than they are from us.